# How do I select attributes with colons in them with XPath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want the `xmlns:fb` attribute from:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"></html>
```

It doesn't work if I use:

```
hxs.select('//html/@xmlns:fb')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `//html/namespace::fb` instead of `//html/@xmlns:fb` to get URI 'http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'

Comment: However, it's a bit of an odd thing to do, since document authors are allowed to choose any namespace prefix they like, and document consumers aren't supposed to care. There are use cases for it, but since you are evidently unfamiliar with namespaces, I would add a strong caveat: are you sure this is what you want to be doing?